# Asp.Net - Identity 2 - Attach files in emails fired by EmailService

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-2

I´m using **Asp.Net-Identity-2** to manage user access in my app.

I´m using EmailService (UserManager.SendEmail) to send confirmation email messages and I´d like to send a formatted HTML message, and I want attach images in it.

How can I do that??

- **Setup Identity User Manager EmailService**

  ```
  public class AppUserManager : UserManager<AppUser>
  {

      public AppUserManager(IUserStore<AppUser> store) : base(store) { }

      public static AppUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<AppUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
      {
          AppUserManager manager = new AppUserManager(new UserStore<AppUser>(db));

          //Some setup code here ....

          //Hook to my EmailService (see class MyEmailService.cs)
          manager.EmailService = new MyEmailService();

          return manager;
      } //Create

  } //class
  ```
- **MyEmailService**

  ```
  public class MyEmailService : IIdentityMessageService
  {

      public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
      {
          MailMessage email = new MailMessage("me@sample.com", message.Destination);
          email.Subject = message.Subject;
          email.Body = message.Body;
          email.IsBodyHtml = true;


          var mailClient = new SmtpClient(); 
          mailClient.Host = "EmailServer";
          mailClient.Port = 25;

          return mailClient.SendMailAsync(email);
      } //SendAsync
  } //class
  ```
- **Action to send email**

  ```
  public ActionResult ForgotPassword(string email)
  {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          AppUser user = UserManager.FindByEmail(email);
          if (user == null || !(UserManager.IsEmailConfirmed(user.Id)))
          {
              return View("../Home/Index");
          } //if

          string code = UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
          string callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Admin", new { Id = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);


          string strMessage = getHTMLMessage(); //variable Html message here, with images references in it (ex. "<img src='cid:IMAGE_TITLE'>")

          UserManager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Message Subject", strMessage);

          return View("../Home/Index");

      }

      // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
      return View();

  } //ForgotPassword
  ```

My doubt is how to attach images in that message...

Thanks for any help..

Julio Schurt

Comment: are you want to send image as attachments or do you have some mail format there are some image to show in mail

Comment: There are images in mail and I need to attach images inline... I know what to do, but not how to define the images when a I call `Usermanager.SendEmail`

Comment: Same problem, one year, no answers :(

Answer (score 1):

I had to create another method in my service and call it directly

```
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Stream>> attach)
    {
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage() { From = new MailAddress("my@email.com") };
        myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
        myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;

        myMessage.Html = message.Body;
        myMessage.Text = message.Body;


        var credentials = new NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypassword");
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        foreach (var file in attach)
        {
            myMessage.AddAttachment(file.Value,file.Key);
        }

        return transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
    }
```

EDIT: (2015-08-14)

Final class:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    const string from = "mail@domain.com";
    const string username = "username";//Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_USER");
    const string pswd = "password";//Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_PASS");
    private List<KeyValuePair<string, Stream>> _attachments;
    private List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _recipients;

    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage() { From = new MailAddress(from) };
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pswd);
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
        if (_recipients != null)
        {
            _recipients.ForEach(r => myMessage.AddTo(string.Format("{0} {1}", r.Key, r.Value)));
        }
        myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        myMessage.Html = message.Body;
        myMessage.Text = message.Body;

        if (_attachments != null)
        {
            foreach (var attachment in _attachments)
            {
                myMessage.AddAttachment(attachment.Value, attachment.Key);
            }
        }

        return transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
    }

    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Stream>> attachments)
    {
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage() { From = new MailAddress(from) };
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pswd);
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
        myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        myMessage.Html = message.Body;
        myMessage.Text = message.Body;

        foreach (var attachment in attachments)
        {
            myMessage.AddAttachment(attachment.Value, attachment.Key);
        }

        return transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
    }

    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message, KeyValuePair<string, Stream> attachment)
    {
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage() { From = new MailAddress(from) };
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pswd);
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
        myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        myMessage.Html = message.Body;
        myMessage.Text = message.Body;
        myMessage.AddAttachment(attachment.Value, attachment.Key);

        return transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
    }

    public void AddTo(string name,string mail)
    {
        _recipients = _recipients ?? new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        _recipients.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(name, string.Format("<{0}>", mail)));
    }

    public void AddAttachment(string name, Stream file)
    {
        _attachments = _attachments ?? new List<KeyValuePair<string, Stream>>();
        _attachments.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Stream>(name, file));
    }

    public void AddAttachment<T>(string name, T records)
    {
        var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(records);
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        ms.Flush();
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);


        _attachments = _attachments ?? new List<KeyValuePair<string, Stream>>();
        _attachments.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Stream>(name, ms));
    }
}
```

Then can use it...

```
// use it directly
                var emailService = new EmailService();
                IdentityMessage msg = new IdentityMessage()
                {
                    Destination = "test <test@domain.com>",
                    Subject = "Subject",
                    Body = "Body"
                };

                emailService.AddTo("Name1", "mail1@domain.com");
                emailService.AddTo("Name2", "mail2@domain.com");
                emailService.AddTo("Name3", "mail3@domaincom");

                emailService.AddAttachment(filename", stream);
                await emailService.SendAsync(msg);

                // Or use it from UserManager
                (UserManager.EmailService as EmailService).AddAttachment("name", yourStream);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync("userid", "subject", "body");
```

Comment: Hello Piyey! Thanks for your answer. Could u show me an example of how can I call this method in my action?

Comment: Hello Julio Schurt, I edited my answer to show you my final class implementation.